# Lack of fit in response surface methodology analysis

Tags: optimization, linear-model, response-surface-methodology

I am trying to optimize a set of variables for a process. To this end, I have conducted a Box Behken design to optimize 3 variables with the R package 'rsm'.

First, I tried the fit of a first-order model where the lack of fit was significant. Then, I fit a second-order model. In this case, the second-order model was significant (p-value < 0.05 and adjusted R-squared > 0.8) however, the lack of fit term remained significant which could mean that the model is wrong.

I am new to this field (DoE) and as far as I have read, I have seen implementations up to second-order models. For this case, would I need to try to fit a third-order model? Re-take data? Take more data at certain points? If you could recommend additional documentation on how to proceed in this situation it would be of great help, thanks in advance.

PD: The summary of the second order model.

> summary(an2)

```
Call:
rsm(formula = Compound ~ SO(x1, x2, x3), data = data_e)

             Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  78.62070    8.92079  8.8132 0.0003123 ***
x1           31.79483    5.46285  5.8202 0.0021145 ** 
x2           -0.46876    5.46285 -0.0858 0.9349489    
x3           26.93490    5.46285  4.9306 0.0043575 ** 
x1:x2         0.03971    7.72563  0.0051 0.9960976    
x1:x3        -2.36949    7.72563 -0.3067 0.7714295    
x2:x3         1.52293    7.72563  0.1971 0.8514915    
x1^2        -17.76825    8.04109 -2.2097 0.0781359 .  
x2^2        -10.13716    8.04109 -1.2607 0.2630552    
x3^2        -14.09955    8.04109 -1.7534 0.1399014    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Multiple R-squared:  0.9303,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8047 
F-statistic: 7.411 on 9 and 5 DF,  p-value: 0.02003

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Compound
                Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value   Pr(>F)
FO(x1, x2, x3)   3 13893.0  4631.0  19.3975 0.003485
TWI(x1, x2, x3)  3    31.7    10.6   0.0443 0.986175
PQ(x1, x2, x3)   3  1998.6   666.2   2.7904 0.148911
Residuals        5  1193.7   238.7                  
Lack of fit      3  1188.5   396.2 153.5421 0.006478
Pure error       2     5.2     2.6                  

Stationary point of response surface:
        x1         x2         x3 
0.83559008 0.04517343 0.88739611 

Stationary point in original units:
Temperature        Weight      Time 
147.5338512   0.6612934  99.9328249 

Eigenanalysis:
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1]  -9.990685 -13.889714 -18.124566

$vectors
          [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
x1 -0.02636044 -0.2877568  0.95734067
x2  0.98152697 -0.1889919 -0.02978063
x3  0.18949919  0.9388707  0.28742296
```